# Execute method on 3rd party exe from my own console application

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

If I where to have the executable: (executable is not a c# application it contains unmanaged code but the code is similar)

```
// ConsoleApplication1.exe

class Program     
{
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter command");

            var input = System.Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "a")
                SomeMethodA();
            else if (input == "b")
                SomeMethodB();
            else if (input == "exit")
                break;
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("invalid command");
        }
    }

    private static void SomeMethodA()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Executing method A");
    }

    private static void SomeMethodB()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Executing method B");
    }
}
```

**Then how could I execute `SomeMethodA()` from c#?**

this is what I have worked out so far

```
        Process p = new Process();

        var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"ConsoleApplication1.exe") 
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        };

        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        p.Start();

        StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;

        var line = string.Empty;

        while ((line = standardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            // here If I send a then ENTER I will execute method A! 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting to pass "a" so SomeMethodA executes you could do this

```
    Process p = new Process();

    var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"ConsoleApplication1.exe") 
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true, //New Line
    };

    p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

    p.Start();

    StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;
    StreamWriter standardInput = p.StandardInput; //New Line

    var line = string.Empty;


    //We must write "a" to the other program before we wait for a answer or we will be waiting forever.
    standardInput.WriteLine("a"); //New Line

    while ((line = standardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        //You can replace "a" with `Console.ReadLine()` if you want to pass on the console input instead of sending "a" every time.
        standardInput.WriteLine("a"); //New Line
    }
```

If you are wanting to bypass the input process all together that is a much harder problem (if the method was not private it would be easier) and I will delete my answer.

---

P.S. You should wrap your two stream reader's in `using` statements

```
using (StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput)
using (StreamWriter standardInput = p.StandardInput)
{
    var line = string.Empty;

    standardInput.WriteLine("a");

    while ((line = standardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        standardInput.WriteLine("a");
    }
}
```